# Facebook login button with html elements

Tags: facebook, authentication, xfbml

About a year ago on our page we included a fb:login-button that instead of simple text for buttons text it had a html element  inside.

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="document.getElementById('buttonid').click();">
<span onclick="some_function();">Login with Facebook</span>
</fb:login-button>
```

The span element is required becouse there is an implementation that handles different clicks (if ctrl is held for example).
This has been working until around 5th June. I have tried to find any information on recent changes but had no luck.
Does anyone know if there is still a way to have html elements inside a fb:login-button tag?